# How to add credentials username and password using an curl api or REST API or crumbissuer in jenkins?

Tags: api, jenkins, curl, credentials

Jenkins is using nginx reverse-proxy.I need to add credentials username and password not by manual steps i.e;jenkins-->manage jenkins-->credentials --->domain--->global-->username&password but by curl api.  Currently I 'm trying with this Trying this curl command inside the pod.

```
CRUMB=$(curl -s -u USERNAME:PASSWORD 'http://ELB-LINK-elb.amazonaws.com/jenkinscore/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)') &&
curl -H $CRUMB -X POST -u USERNAME:PASSWORD 'https://ELB-LINK-elb.amazonaws.com/jenkinscore/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials' \
--data-urlencode 'json={
  "": "0",
  "credentials": {
    "scope": "GLOBAL",
    "id": "identity",
    "username": "USER",
    "password": "PASS",
    "description": "CRED",
    "$class": "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl"
  }
}'
```

Comment: I have resolved this .<defaultCrumbIssuer _class='hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer'>
<crumb>056329837273029038302</crumb>
<crumbRequestField>Crumb-Jenk</crumbRequestField>
</defaultCrumbIssuer>

Comment: so The TOKEN = CRUMB REQUEST FIELD : CRUMB.                            curl -H Crumb-Jenk:056329837273029038302 -X POST -u USERNAME:PASSWORD 'https://ELB-LINK/jenkinscore/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials' --data-urlencode 'json={
  "": "0",
  "credentials": {
    "scope": "GLOBAL",
    "id": "identity",
    "username": "USER",
    "password": "PASS",
    "description": "CRED",
    "$class": "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl"
  }
}' --insecure